# No style applied using AndroidImageSlider

Tags: android

I'm using AndroidImageSlider (https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) in my app but I cant apply custom design in the page indicator. I'm using Eclipse, I download the proyect and add as a library

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:background="@color/azul_us"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Magnifier_Oval_Black" />
</LinearLayout>

 <style name="AndroidImageSlider_Magnifier_Oval_Black">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="shape">rect</item>
        <item name="padding_left">3dp</item>
        <item name="padding_right">3dp</item>
        <item name="padding_top">4dp</item>
        <item name="padding_bottom">4dp</item>

        <item name="selected_color">#7ac943</item>
        <item name="unselected_color">#33000000</item>
        <item name="selected_width">8dp</item>
        <item name="selected_height">8dp</item>
        <item name="unselected_width">6dp</item>
        <item name="unselected_height">6dp</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot add this line

```
slider.setCustomIndicator((PagerIndicator) findViewById(R.id.custom_indicator));
```